# Find the index of an element in an array with cuda c++

Tags: c++, cuda

I am new with cuda.

I have two arrays:

```
  int* AA = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
  int* BB = new int[5]{ 2,2,2,4,4 };
```

and I want to find the index of every element in AA that is equal to each element in BB that in this case is

```
{1,1,1,3,3}
```

---

here is My code:

```
__global__ void findIndex(int* A, int* B, int* C)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;


    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if (B[i] == A[j])
        {
            C[i] = j;

        }
    }
}


int main() {

    int* AA = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
    int* BB = new int[5]{ 2,2,2,4,4 };
    int* CC = new int[5]{ 0,0,0,0,0 };

    int(*ppA), (*ppB), (*ppC);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&ppA, (5) * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&ppB, (5) * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&ppC, (5) * sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(ppA, AA, 5 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(ppB, BB, 5 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(ppC, CC, 5 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int numBlocks = 1;
    dim3 threadsPerBlock(5);
    findIndex << <numBlocks, threadsPerBlock >> > (ppA, ppB, ppC);


    cudaMemcpy(CC, ppC, 5 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
        printf("%d ", CC[m]);
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
{1,2,3,0,0}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use a library like thurst, write some code. Many possibilities

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to write it my self, for some reasons...

Comment: Thanks Robert, I am not writing homework!!:)) this is my full problem:
I have two arrays with different sizes and need to find the index of every element in the first array that math in the second array, I wrote some code but it does not result what I want...

Comment: If the intention is to get the index, why does you code store the *value* of each match it finds?

Comment: What should happen, when there are several indices with value 4? Cannot happen? Get back any one of the results? Get back list of results? I would suggest, you try to write a normal function first, which correctly does the task, and then try to port it to Cuda.

Comment: You can try printf from within CUDA code to further debug, but best is to also print out i in each line or do it for only one specific i with an if clause. printf needs the stdio.h header

Answer (score -1):

Simplest non-stable single-gpu solution would be using atomics, something like this:

```
__global__ void find(int * arr,int * counter, int * result)
{
    int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    if(arr[id] == 4)
    {
        int ctr = atomicAdd(counter,1);
        result[ctr] = id;
    }
}
```

this way you can have an array of results in "result" array and if the wanted number is sparse it wouldn't slowdown much (like only few in whole source array). This is not an optimal way for multi-gpu systems, though. Requires host-side coordination between gpus, unless a special CUDA feature from newest toolkit is used (for system-level atomics).

If number of 4s leads to a "dense" arr array or if you have multiple gpus, then you should look for other solutions like stream compaction. First select the cells containing 4 as a mask. Then do the compaction. Some Nvidia blogs or tutorials have this algorithm.

For the "atomic" solution (especially on "shared" memory atomics), Maxwell (and onwards) architecture is much better than Kepler, just in case you still use a Kepler. Also using atomics is not exactly reproducible as the order of atomic operations can not be known. **You will get a differently-ordered result array most of the time.** But the *stream compaction* preserves the result order. This may save you from writing a sorting algorithm (like bitonic-sort, shear-sort, etc) on top of it.

Comment: Do I have to #include specific header to work with atomicAdd?
because I get the undefined error...